# How to Restrict Developing iOS app only for iPhone 6+ & iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

I would like to develop a Universal iOS app but only for iPhone 6Plus and iPad !

There is a way to do it or it will be Rejected from Apple ?

Comment: I suppose Apple will not rejected. I use UISplitViewController and I pretend to use in Iphone 6 Plus (and obviously Ipad) but for other Iphones i will use other Storyboard specially design for those devices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a very elegant way to do this with how the IOS store is set up. In the apple store there is only the choice to have apps for either iPad, iPhone, or both. The best that you could probably do is set your app up for both and then only set it up to work for iPhone 6 plus and iPad within your own app. Then in the description of the app store you could specify that you have to have iPhone 6 Plus or iPad to use it. I think Apple would probably accept this but it is Apple so who knows.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. Anyone found a way to achieve this?